# TFS How to Build Visual Studio-based "Open Folder" CMake project

Tags: tfs, cmake, visual-studio-2017, arm

I have an ARM-GCC project, which is configured and built using Visual Studio's native "Open folder..." CMake project support (introduced in VS2017).  All of our needed build settings are stored in CMakeSettings.json.

I would like to build this project using our TFS Continuous Integration server.

I've confirmed that our build server contains all of the prerequisites provided 'out of the box' by the Visual Studio 2017 installer - CMake, Ninja, and ARM-GCC compilers.  These tools are all installed to a 'standard' Visual Studio tooling location:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Linux\gcc_arm
- etc.

These tools 'just work' out of the box, when we open the project using Visual Studio's `"File" -> "Open Folder..."` approach.  Within TFS however, we can't seem to get the solution to build.  I've tried a few different approaches within the build definition...

**Option 1: 'Visual Studio' task**

This approach complains about a missing sln/proj file:

> Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does
>   not contain a project or solution file.

There *is* no project or solution file, because it is an "Open Folder" project, with a `CMakeSettings.json` file, instead...

**Option 2: 'MSBuild' Task**

I have not found a set of command-line options capable of building a CMake project folder, using MSBuild.

**Option 3: 'CMake' Task**

When adding a CMake task to the build definition, the build server complains that it does not fulfill the auto-generated "cmake" ability prerequisite, despite the fact that Visual Studio has installed the cmake tool.

Has anyone successfully completed a TFS automated build of a Visual Studio-hosted "Open Folder..." CMake project?